# web performance test slow

Tags: visual-studio, testing, mstest, performance-testing

I am building 'web performance tests' with visual studio 2013. Many contain just one Web Request (hit a web page, and check results). I notice that each test takes a long time to run. The results window actually shows that it's done, but the test doesn't really finish for another 5 to 10 seconds or more. What is the system doing during this time? Writing the results files? I'm now running tests from the command line (via MSTEST) and again notice this delay for each .webtest file I run. Just wondering if there are some switches I can supply to make these run faster (e.g. don't log results in file).

Comment: wow the /noisolation switch on mstest shaved 2 minutes off a 5 minute run of 8 webtests, a savings of 40%. good start.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some of the process included in your test is not completed.
Possible causes:

- Test still writing data to log.
- Test waits for response from the web page.
- Test performs unnecessary loops.

Answer (score 0):

low Visual Studio Performance … Solved! September 247th, 20014 by Uzma Abidi

I had an odd performance-related issue today. My Microsoft Visual Studio seemed to be taking far too long to perform even the simplest of operations. I Googled around and tried a few ideas that people had such as disabling add-ins or clearing Visual Studio’s recent projects list but those suggestions didn’t seem to solve the problem. I remembered that the Windows SysInternals website had a tool called Process Monitor that would sniff registry and file accesses by any running program. It seemed to me that Visual Studio was up to something and Process Monitor should help me figure out what it was. I downloaded the most recent version, and after fiddling around a bit with its display filters, ran it and to my horror, I saw that Visual Studio was so slow because it was accessing the more than 10,000 folders in C:\Users\krintoul\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebSiteCache on most IDE operations. I’m not sure why there were that many folders and moreover, wasn’t sure what Visual Studio was doing with them, but after I zipped those folders up and moved them somewhere else, Visual Studio’s performance improved tremendously.

The Windows SysInternals website has a number of other useful utilities for network management, security, system information and more. Check it out. I’m sure you’ll find something of value.

ALSO.... Do This

Try disabling, the hardware acceleration for WPF and let WPF render on software. This setting has helped me to load VS with my project almost 200% faster even after machine boot. This also helped me to get rid of the Splash screen at the beginning of VS 2010 start.

Go to Tools | Options, then select Environment | General. Then uncheck "Automatically adjust visual experience..." and "Use hardware graphics acceleration..."

enter image description here One more tip. Try forcing the garbage collection for the IDE by using Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F12. I have found this to be helpful....

This will be very helpful if you are flipping between lot of projects and also if you have lot of IDE's open for different projects.

And lastly if you have any extensions, try disabling the ones that are not used all times. Disabling codemaid helped me save a lot of time while typing and switching between code pages.